# javascript function doesn't work in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to call a JavaScript function inside PHP code,This function return a number, the Result for example is : http://localhost/1.php?id=fn(3)
as you see this function cannot be interpreted by the browser I already tried ' ' or " " But I get the same problem, normally I must receive for example http://localhost/1.php?id=3
 Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fn(a)
{  
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    var res=table.rows[a].cells[0].innerHTML;
    return res;
}
</script>
<table class="table " id="tableId">

  <?php 
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * from jeux_video');
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()){  
 echo "
  <tr  onclick=\"location.href='1.php?id=fn($donnees[ID])'\">
 ";   
 ?>
  <td id="td1"><?php echo $donnees['ID']?></td>
  <td><?php echo $donnees['nom']?></td>
  <td><?php echo $donnees['possesseur']?></td>
  <td><?php echo $donnees['prix']?></td>
 </tr>
   <?php }  $reponse ->closeCursor(); ?>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: which is it `?id=3 ` or `?id=fn(3)`  ??

Comment: if this function work normally I must receive ?id=3

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Everything seems alright code wise, though you aren't doing anything with the result of the JavaScript function. Can you give us the exact problem you are seeing?

Comment: This ligne does not work When I click in table this link appears http://localhost/tpphp/1.php?id=fn(3), I want http://localhost/tpphp/1.php?id=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you're putting on the `href` won't be parsed as a javascript expression, but just as a string.

You need to output a valid javascript statement for the `fn` call to execute:

```
echo "<tr onclick=\"location.href='1.php?id=' + fn(".$donnees[ID].")\">";
```

This will output:

```
<tr onclick="location.href='1.php?id=' + fn(3)">
```

Comment: No problem, make sure to mark an answer as correct if it solved your issue

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on the server, and Javascript on the client.  That's the rule.  If you want PHP to output a value anywhere in your document, you need to do it with PHP:

```
echo "<tr onclick=\"location.href='1.php?id=' + fn(" . $donnees[ID] . ")'\">"; // ...
```

As it is, this is likely the exact markup that is being output:

```
<tr  onclick=\"location.href='1.php?id=fn($donnees[ID])'\">
```

Which, to Javascript, makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
location.href = '1.php?id=fn(3)'
```

JavaScript isn't going to automatically evaluate code inside of a string.  You have to execute the code itself and concatenate its result to the string.  Something like this:

```
location.href = '1.php?id=' + fn(3)
```

Comment: Yes, echo "<tr onclick=\"location.href='1.php?id=' + fn(" . $donnees[ID] . ")'\">"; work fine, thank you for your help